# Richfaces Using multiple forms with a4j:ajax

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have this page:

```
      <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="someForm">
            Form is here
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <a4j:commandButton id="editButton" value="editSomeString"
                            execute="@this"
                            action="#{testBean.edit('afterEdit')}"
                            oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPanel')}.show()"
                            render="editPanel"/>
            <rich:popupPanel modal="true" id="editPanel" autosized="true"
                          domElementAttachment="form">
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <a4j:ajax event="show" oncomplete="alert('#{testBean.someString}')" />
                </f:facet>
                Changed value is          
                #{testBean.someString}
            </rich:popupPanel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

With this bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

public TestBean() {
    someString = "initValue";
}
private String someString;


public String getSomeString() {
    return someString;
}


public void setSomeString(String someString) {
    this.someString = someString;
}


public void edit(String value) {
   someString = value;
}
```

}

Now if I click the button in popup I will have correct value (afterEdit) and in alert box the old one (initValue).
If I remove first form (id=someForm) or change bean scope to session it works just fine (afterEdit value showed in alert box).
Any ideas what is going on?

I use this dependencies for jsf:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-b04</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-b04</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

along with  richfaces 4.0.0.Final and GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23)

Another variation of same page (onhide and onshow methods added)

```
<h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="someForm">
            Form is here
        </h:form> 
        <h:form>
            <a4j:commandButton id="editButton" value="go"
                            execute="@this"
                            action="#{testBean.edit('afterEdit')}"
                            oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPanel')}.show()"
                            render="editPanel,y"/>
            <rich:popupPanel modal="true" id="editPanel" autosized="true"
                             styleClass="taskEditPanel" domElementAttachment="form" onhide="alert('from on hide #{testBean.someString}')" onshow="alert('from on show #{testBean.someString}')">
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <a4j:ajax event="show" oncomplete="alert('show complete #{testBean.someString}')"  />
                    <a4j:ajax event="hide" oncomplete="alert('hide complete  #{testBean.someString}')"/>
                </f:facet>
                Changed value is           
                #{testBean.someString}
                 <a4j:commandButton id="exitButton" value="exit"
                            execute="@this"
                            oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPanel')}.hide()"
                            />
            </rich:popupPanel>
        </h:form> 
    </h:body>
```

If You try to open and close popup those alerts appear:

1. "from on show afterEdit"
2. "show complete initValue"
3. "from on hide afterEdit"
4. "hide complete initValue"

So it looks like a4j:ajax getting value from somewhere else than methods on popup?
Is it a ViewState problem? There are two hidden javax.faces.ViewState fields with same id and different values. Do they represent the state of whole view or only form they are included in? If whole view these two fields should have the same values and maybe it is posiible that a4j:ajax is looking at view state from first form which is not updated?
Any links to resources on how view state is handled and what does it represent would be great (even if view state is not the case here)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the same form and`a4j:region` to separatte the different forms, because jsf doesn't like to update other forms since they state isn't sended to the server
When you use `sessionScope` the state is saved in the server making possible that, but it's not the best solution for real web apps

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am aware that using one form with regions will work just fine and already did it to resolve the prolblem. But I would like to know what exactly causing the problem. Since those two forms do not interact with each other (i tried adding render on a4j:ajax to be sure not to rerender that first form) why does it happen?

Comment: The problem is simple, when a form is submited to the server, it goes with his component id, making the server get the view of the form, the form wich sended the request, so if you tried to update values outside that form they will simply being ignored, one solution is to include the other form in the execute param of the command button or link, but the values will be sended to, other solution is call the click in a button in the other form with javascript

Comment: And i know, it's very sad, i have been forced to use that javascript solution more than once, but it's looks like there is not other way since is the way jsf 2 works, it's planned to work with one form... and many other beautifull stuff that you will find

Comment: You said that "if you tried to update values outside that form...". But i did not. In my page the first form does nothing and second one updates only fields within itself. Or maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: Changing javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD to server resolve the problem. So as @rekiem87 wrote it is state saving problem. Still trying to figure it out.